# ARM - convert string to float in hardware?

Tags: string, floating-point, arm, raspberry-pi, type-conversion

I am trying a new raspberry pi.
Many recommend to use glibc strtod and family as an answer to this question.

But I put myself in an assembly project without any library.

I read about the `fcvt`arm instruction, but it only converts integer to float.

String could be "14.58" and I should get the **ieee-754** equivalent `0 10000010 11010010100011110101110` (spaces are for convenience only here).

#### Question:

Is there any way `fcvt` could help me to convert that string to a ieee754 float? Or anything else in hardware? (and faster than the software long divisions)

#### Edit:

Maybe I could parse the string up to the optional ".", convert that part from integer to float in hardware; do the same with the rest of the string after the dot, divide it by power of ten according to the number of figures, and add the two parts.. waw..

**Maybe** it could be fast enough.

Comment: i'm wondering how you pass the string to the machine in the first place, it sounds quite impossible with a keyboard, with assembly. and also why assembly?

Comment: I get this string from network. Assembly is just to develop my arm assembly skills. It is of use for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FVCT` instructions can only convert:

- Integer to floating point
- Fixed point (ie integer divided by a power of 2) to floating point

So none that can convert string to float.

I mostly agree with your edit (with some modifications). You should:

- Find the position of the dot (How many digits after the dot) and remove it from the string (ie shift left all remaining characters)
- Convert the string (without dot) to integer
- Convert the integer to float (VCVT)
- divide (in float) the result by 10^(number of digits after dot). This is supported by the hardware. You absolutely need to do it in float otherwise you will loose far too much precision.

Alternatively, you can also call a function like `sscanf`...

Comment: I realize that we agree on the flow. I may not have expressed it that way but this is it. This is the only way to make it happen without all the software implementation. Thanks Dric512.